# Is livedata builder ok for one-shot operations?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

For example, let's say that we have a product catalog view with an option to add product to a cart.
Each time when user clicks add to cart, a viewModel method addToCart is called, that could look like this:

```
//inside viewModel
fun addToCart(item:Item): LiveData<Result> = liveData {
    val result = repository.addToCart(item) // loadUser is a suspend function.
    emit(result)
}


//inside view
addButton.onClickListener = {
     viewModel.addToCart(selectedItem).observe (viewLifecycleOwner, Observer () {
          result -> //show result
    }
}
```

What happens after adding for example, 5 items -> will there be 5 livedata objects in memory observed by the view?

If yes, when will they be cleanup?  And if yes, should we avoid livedata builder for one-shot operations that can be called multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation seems wrong! You are constantly returning a new `LiveData` object for every `addToCard` function call. About your first question, it's a `Yes`.

If you want to do it correctly via liveData.

```kotlin
// In ViewModel

private val _result = MutableLiveData<Result>()
val result: LiveData<Result>
   get() = _result;

fun addToCart(item: Item) {
   viewModelScope.launch {
      // Call suspend functions
      result.value = ...
   }
}

// Activity/Fragment

viewModel.result.observe(lifecycleOwner) { result ->
   // Process the result  
   ...
}

viewModel.addToCart(selectedItem)
```

All you have to do is call it from activity & process the result. You can also use [`StateFlow`](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow) for this purpose. It also has an extension `asLiveData` which converts Flow -> LiveData as well.

Comment: Your answer points to the "right" way, but you did not answer the question why it is wrong and what happens "when constantly returning a new LiveData" .

Comment: According to OP's code, it will call the observer only once when the button is clicked & further subsequent calls will create it's new instance & call the observer only once. Eventually, those previous `LiveData` objects should be automatically garbage collected.

Comment: @kaustubhpatange
thanks, your answer is exactly how I am doing this at the moment -> but, I've asked this question because I've found in multiple places suggestion that MutableLiveData can or even should be replaced with a new livedata builder block, and this was my concern regarding it - looks like it's not safe for repeatable one-shot actions.

Comment: "repeatable one-shot" = paradox! If you want a one-shot LiveData, which is often the case for navigation events, then instantiating the live data each time a subscriber wants to subscribe is a very simple way to achieve that. That obviously only works where a single subscriber is expected. Doing otherwise, i.e. reusing an instance, creates the problem for which SingleLiveEvent intends to solve. Why create extra problems?

Answer (score 1):

According to `LiveData` implementation of:

```java
    public void observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull Observer<? super T> observer) {
        assertMainThread("observe");
        if (owner.getLifecycle().getCurrentState() == DESTROYED) {
            // ignore
            return;
        }
        LifecycleBoundObserver wrapper = new LifecycleBoundObserver(owner, observer);
        ObserverWrapper existing = mObservers.putIfAbsent(observer, wrapper);
        if (existing != null && !existing.isAttachedTo(owner)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot add the same observer"
                    + " with different lifecycles");
        }
        if (existing != null) {
            return;
        }
        owner.getLifecycle().addObserver(wrapper);
    }
```

a new Observer (`wrapper`) is added every time you observe a LiveData. Looking at this I would be carefull creating new Observers from a view (click) event. At the moment I can not tell if a Garbage Collector can free this resources.

As @kaustubhpatange mentioned, you should have one LiveData with a state/value that can be changed by the viewModel, with every new result. That LiveData can be observed (once) in your Activity or Fragment `onCreate()` function:

```kotlin
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

  viewModel.result.observe(lifecycleOwner) { result ->
    // handle the result
  }
}
```

Using MutableLiveData in your ViewModel, you can mostly create LiveData only once, and populate it later with values from click events, responses etc.

Comment: thank you, this is the way I am doing it at the moment...I was trying to evaluate if I should switch to livedata { } builder, but you just confirmed my concerns regarding multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

If your operation is One-Shot use `Coroutine` and `LiveData`.

If your operation serving with ***Streams*** you can use `Flow`.

For **one-shot** operations, your approach it's OK.
I think with `liveData` builder there is no any Memory leak.
If you use for example private backing property for `LiveData` and observe an public `LiveData` it might occurs different behavior like get latest value before assign new value to that.